# How do you add a custom route to a singleton resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

```
map.resource  :basket, :collection => { :checkout => :post }
```

The above does not work for a resource, as you would expect since basket is a resource (ie. singular) not resources, so there is no concept of a collection, everything should be scoped to the current_user. In this case User has_one Basket.

However I would like to specify a custom route without having to resort to adding another line in routes, eg:

```
map.checkout 'basket/checkout', :controller => 'baskets', :action => 'checkout'
```

Is this possible?

Of course my other option is to add a checkouts controller.

Comment: I've often wondered the same thing and I've always had to resort to just writing a manual named route as you mentioned above, good Q!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `:member` option instead of `:collection`:

```
map.resource :basket, :member => {:checkout => :post}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the basket is scoped to the user I'd make it a nested resource:

```
map.resources :users do |users|
  users.resource :basket, :member => { :checkout => :post }
end

... or in Rails 3 ...

resources :users do
  resource :basket do
    post :checkout, :on => :member
  end
end
```

This way you'll be able to scope the basket to the user who's checking out.  The URL will end up looking like this:

```
/users/5/basket/checkout
```

You also get the nicely worded named route 'checkout_user_basket'.